# Show/Hide Bootstrap modal according to a condition in React

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, hide, show

I'm working on a react project and I want to toggle a bootstrap modal according to a api call response. `data-dismiss="modal"` is working on the buttons, But what i need is to show/ hide according to a condition.

eg:

```
if(x=10){
  //show the modal
}
else{
 //hide the modal
}
```

any suggestions please!

Comment: you can use a state variable and change it according to your api response which should be passed down to modal as a prop

Answer (score 0):

There is not nearly enough detail here to properly and directly answer your question. Where is your actual code? You'll need to provide more than an empty if/else statement for the help to arrive.

With that being said, if you're making an API call in React, may I assume you're using Axios? Have the response activate a boolean value in your state, should will hide or show the value as you desire after the successful response arrives.

Again, it's difficult to know context or if this is a successful answer with no context to work from. I hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I basically use jquery to show or hide bootstrap modal in React.

Below is what you have to do to handle modal as you needed. Here myModal is id of modal parent div

```
 if(x=10){
    //show the modal
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }
  else{
      //hide the modal
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the modal a separate component.

```
function myModal(props) {
  return(
    <div>
      <Modal isOpen={props.open}>
        // ModalHead, ModalBody, etc
      </Modal>
    </div>
  };
}
```

And in the parent component's `render()` method, pass the show/hide information to the modal component:

```
let show = x === 10;
<myModal open={show} />
```

If you only want to show the modal under a certain condition, you can also use ternary operator and in this case we don't need the *open* props:

```
{x === 10 ? <myModal /> : ""}
```

Comment: Can you explain why not x === 10 with out brackets

Comment: @Nelles I thought parentheses make it more intuitive. Just now I realized that Prettier would wipe off these 'useless' parentheses so thanks for pointing out and I have edited my answer.